# How to use AngularJS typeahead with asynchronous and custom templates for results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

I'm trying to use Angular Typeahead to return an object rather than the string search but I can't get it to work. Here's my code in the controller:

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
  return $http.get(API_PROVIDER.full_path + 'users.json', {
    params: {
      first_name: val,
      _role: 'voiceArtist'
    }
  }).then(function(resultonse){
    return resultonse.data.users.map(function(item){
      return item;
    });
  });
};
```

And in my view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search here" typeahead="name.first_name for name in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:{first_name:$viewValue}" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
```

But all I get back is the string. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved at the end. It was the order of it I was getting wrong. Instead of

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search here" typeahead="name.first_name for name in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:{first_name:$viewValue}" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
```

Should be this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="voice.voiceArtist" placeholder="Search voice artist" typeahead="state as state.first_name for state in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:{name:$viewValue}" class="form-control">
```